# Want to examine effect of both specific covariates and their sum in regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

I have a regression model that I am using for explanatory purposes. I have a set of binary covariates which are specific comorbid diseases. I also have a variable which is the sum of comorbid diseases (categorical). I would like to examine the effects of both on an outcome.

I ran the 2 models separately and the results of all other covariates are nearly identical. My initial thought is to report the results of model 1 (individual diseases) and then also include the CIs of the sum variable, with an asterisk indicating how the model was ran twice. Perhaps averaging the results of other covariates between the 2 models.

Is there a standard methodology for this scenario? I want to report this in a single table and am having trouble researching this specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a specific hypothesis, you could consider using AIC (Akaike Information Criterion) to assess the relative quality of your two models. For example:

```
mdl1 <- GLM(outcome ~ disease1 + disease2 + ...)
mdl2 <- GLM(outcome ~ total_diseases)
```

Then you can calculate the AIC for each model, and compare them. Most statistical packages have functions for calculating AIC. Some good rules of thumb to start off with:

- the absolute value of AIC doesn't matter, it's only the difference between AICs that matter
- use the small-sample corrected version AICc if you have a small sample
- you must compare models fit to the same dataset (same number of rows & outcomes)
- the lower the AIC, the better
- models with AIC within 2 of each other are roughly equivalent
- AIC will not tell you if your model is shit - you need other things like residual plots to assess this

AIC will "penalise" complicated models but "reward" models which fit the data well.